# Wordpress blank page in localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, wsod

I downloaded the Wordpress Site via FTP, but I can't access in wp-admin, homepage...

If I create a test.html file, show page Blank.

WP_DEBUG is set to TRUE, but not returns a error.

I rename the theme folder, and the plugins folder, but nothing happen, blank page.

If in the index.php file I add this code die(Hello World!); show message, so, it's access to index.php.

It's only happen in localhost, in the production environment it's works fine.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to get started.

1. Download the wp-content folder from FTP
2. Export your MySQL database.(You can find DB name from wp-config.php)
3. install new WordPress on local
4. replace the wp-content with your downloaded wp-content
5. Drop all tables of new WordPress and import your downloaded database on local.
6. update website URL from wp-option table
7. update table prefix in wp-config.php file

Now your ready to access the live website on local.
Once you login the website updates the permalinks. I know this process is long but there is no way you get error.

Happy Migration

Answer (score 0):

I can Fix this.

The problem is in the file wp-load.php, I replace this file with another versión wordpress.